# Can I still have several email addresses under one account?

Tags: email

At one time I had several email addresses under one mac dot com account. Is that option still available? I cannot find the option anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an old account you can still choose to enable to work with old domains like mac.com or me.com in the diffrence settings as for example Messages or FaceTime.

If you want to use your old mail addresses in Mail.app, you have to enable them in:

> https://www.icloud.com/#mail/prefs-addresses

New created icloud.com addresses can only be used with that domain, and don't have access any longer to the me.com or mac.com domains.

Hope that helped you!